# How to Constantly get rotation/eulerAngles values of ARCamera

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

Hey I an trying to constantly get the value of the devices camera / ARCamera. As far as I know there is only one function the allows me to access these ARCamera traits. That is this function here:

Code:

```
 // Only gets called couple times when camera state changes 

 func session(_ session: ARSession, cameraDidChangeTrackingState camera: ARCamera) 

  print("\(camera.eulerAngles)")

 }
```

I've been thinking about maybe using some trickery like putting a repeating timer in the function that would call that value. But I can't call a local selectors that get booted out. What I'm more looking for is something along the lines of how this function is:

```
func renderer(_ aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
 // This constantly gets called. 
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to incorporate the ARCamera into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continuously get updates on camera state, implement [`ARSessionDelegate.session(_:didUpdate:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate/2865611-session):

```
class MyDelegate: ARSessionDelegate {

  func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    print("\(frame.camera)")
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

The ARFrame object shall contain `camera` field with all the necessary information.

---

If you just want to know when tracking state changes, you might want to store the state from `session(_:cameraDidChangeTrackingState:)` in a field, and refer to it in your rendering loop:

```
class MyDelegate: SCNSceneRendererDelegate, ARSessionObserver {

  var camera: ARCamera! = nil

  func session(_ session: ARSession, cameraDidChangeTrackingState camera: ARCamera) {
    self.camera = camera
  }

  func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    print("\(self.camera.trackingState)")
  }

  /* ... more methods ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer much appreciated but the unfortunate part is that the (cameraDidChangeTrackingState) only gets called when the state changes. So it doesn't actually up date the camera.eulerAngles / traits. every second. So the (updateAtTime) will just keep printing the same thing. Its unfortunate that there in no information on this yet. As ARKits only a-couple days old.

Comment: You can make your class `ARSessionDelegate`, which shall receive `session(_:didUpdate:)`. The second argument is just an ARFrame that contains a `camera` field with the current ARCamera instance. More: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate/2865611-session